# Fade out using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout

down menu and I am using jquery to fade-in. Problem is I cant find how to fade it back out once mouse leaves area. I have one title, when hovered over shows 3 dropdowns under one div name. Problem is once it fades-in I cant get it to fade out when mouse is not in  tag which all divs are in . Please help

```
Code:

<JQuery>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".menu-ite").hover(function(){
        $(".menu-item").fadeIn();
        $(".menu-item").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".menu-item").fadeIn(3000);

    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery's [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method accepts two handers: handlerIn and handlerOut, "to be executed when the mouse pointer *enters* and *leaves* the elements". Syntax: `.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`.

Comment: Basically once I hover over parent Div , all the other fadeIn. Great . Though they stay there forever which is not what I want , I want them to fadeOut when I leave. Thank you very much to anyone whom can help me in this solution. I have checked other solutions and none fit. :} Much appreciated

Comment: Oh my goodness. Thank you so much both of you. I realise I have come across as a complete amateur . Which in these terms I unfortunately am . I thank you both for your fast responses and correct judgements. Many thanks for both informative and fast responses. I will pass on to my peers the niceties shown here. Great support from members. You are the sort of individuals that make me smile.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu-item").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //Do stuff when mouse hovers
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //Do stuff when mouse leaves
    }
});
```

You can do multiple things with the `.on()` handler.

`.hover()` has it's own handler, which you can read more about here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Alternatively, if you're working with objects made after the document is ready, you can use this:

```
$(".menu-item").on('mouseenter', '.selector', function() {
    //Do stuff when mouse hovers
});
$(.menu-item").on('mouseleave', '.selector', function() {
    //Do stuff when mouse leaves
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-item").hover(function(){
    $(".menu-item").fadeIn();
    $(".menu-item").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".menu-item").fadeIn(3000);
  }, function(){
    $(".menu-item").fadeOut();
    $(".menu-item").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".menu-item").fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
```

reference: https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1